# powershell array sorting posting json vice-versa

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I have an issue with putting array elements into JSON.
Here is my script:

```
function UpdateJSON() 
{
param (    
    [string] $ApplicationSettingUserValue,
    [string] $ApplicationSettingPassValue
)
$JSON = Get-Content $File| Out-String | ConvertFrom-JSON
$arrayUsers = @{"username"=$ApplicationSettingUserValue; "password"=$ApplicationSettingPassValue}
$JSON.users  | Add-Member  -Type NoteProperty -Name 'test_user' -Value $arrayUsers
ConvertTo-Json $JSON | Set-Content "..\Desktop\json\users.json"
}
```

In Output I receive the following JSON:

```
{
    "users":  {
                  "test user":  {   
                                    "password":  "TestUser1pass",
                                    "username":  "username"
                                }
              }
}
```

The thing is, that when I'm trying to add the third variable into an array the order becomes right in the output: username, password and . Otherwise, the password and username add in the wrong order. 
I tried to put elements into array vice-versa however, nothing changes. 
Does anyone know what did I miss?

The required output is:

```
{
    "users":  {
                  "test user":  {   
                                    "username":  "username",
                                    "password":  "TestUser1pass"

                                }
              }
}
```

Comment: try removing the `Out-String` stage from your pipeline. that both converts your neatly arranged lines of text into ONE multiline string --- it also adds things like newline chars to them. it can make your code fail since you are not dealing with proper lines of text.

Comment: Define `$arrayUsers` as `$arrayUsers = [ordered]@{"username"=…`

Comment: Thank you!!! [ordered] is exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 0):

As commented by [@JozefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz), the work arround for this issue is to use an ordered dictionary:

```
$arrayUsers = [ordered]@{"username"=$ApplicationSettingUserValue; "password"=$ApplicationSettingPassValue}
```

### Background

The [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6) cmdlet returns objects (`[PSCustomObject]`) rather than hashtables by default (unless you use the [`-AsHashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6#parameters) parameter):

```
$Json.users.'test user'.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

Or, if you want to reveal the whole PowerShell structure:

```
ConvertTo-Expression $Json    # https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression

[pscustomobject]@{'users' = [pscustomobject]@{'test user' = [pscustomobject]@{
                        'username' = 'username'
                        'password' = 'TestUser1pass'
                }}}
```

Note that the properties of a `PSCustomObject` are also ordered.

Meaning, you might use the `[ordered]` type to created additional users:

```
$arrayUsers = [Ordered]@{username = 'user2'; password = 'pwd2'}
$Json.users | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name 'test user2' -Value $arrayUsers
```

But that will give you different user objects:

```
$Json.Users | ConvertTo-Expression

[pscustomobject]@{
        'test user' = [pscustomobject]@{
                'username' = 'username'
                'password' = 'TestUser1pass'
        }
        'test user2' = [ordered]@{
                'username' = 'user2'
                'password' = 'pwd2'
        }
}
```

But it is actually better to create additional user objects using the `[pscustomobject]` type:

```
$arrayUsers = [PSCustomObject]@{username = 'user2'; password = 'pwd2'}
$JSON.users | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name 'test user2' -Value $arrayUsers
$Json.Users | ConvertTo-Expression

[pscustomobject]@{
        'test user' = [pscustomobject]@{
                'username' = 'username'
                'password' = 'TestUser1pass'
        }
        'test user2' = [pscustomobject]@{
                'username' = 'user2'
                'password' = 'pwd2'
        }
}
```

It doesn't matter for the end result (if you serialize the whole object using `ConvertTo-Json`) but it might, if you want manipulate the user list (e.g. sorting) prior serializing it.